# Getting "Platform unknown on host switch1" error while executing ansible playbook for Dell OS6 switch

Tags: python, ansible, switch-statement

I have an issue with my playbook for my Dell OS6 switch.

Here is the playbook:

```
- name: Change password switch
  hosts: switch1
  become: true
  become_method: enable

  roles:
    - dell_os6_users
```

Here is my task role:

```
- name: Load secrets
  include_vars: "secret.yml"

- name: Change user password
  ansible.netcommon.cli_command:
    username: "{{ username }}"
    password: "{{ old_password }}"
    command: "username {{ username }} password {{ new_password }} privilege 15"
  when: "'Command successful' in version_output.stdout_lines[0]"

- name: Verify new password works
  ansible.netcommon.cli_command:
    username: "{{ username }}"
    password: "{{ new_password }}"
    command: "show version"
  register: verify_output
  when: "'Command successful' in version_output.stdout_lines[0]"

- name: Print verification output
  debug:
    var: verify_output.stdout_lines
```

When I ran it, I received an error that I couldn't resolve even after many attempts (see below):

```
redirecting (type: become) ansible.builtin.enable to ansible.netcommon.enable
<XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: test123
<XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d10 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="test123"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/ezeqielle/.ansible/cp/bf6c4719ad XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~test123 && sleep 0'"'"''
<XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX> (0, b'\r\n\r\nInvalid input detected.\r\n', b'')
<XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: test123
<XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d10 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="test123"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/ezeqielle/.ansible/cp/bf6c4719ad XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo Invalid input detected./.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo Invalid input detected./.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1683117228.0405338-81602-55975537376862 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1683117228.0405338-81602-55975537376862="` echo Invalid input detected./.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1683117228.0405338-81602-55975537376862 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX> (0, b'\r\n\r\nInvalid input detected.\r\n', b'')
<switch1> Attempting python interpreter discovery
<XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: test123
<XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d10 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="test123"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/ezeqielle/.ansible/cp/bf6c4719ad XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo PLATFORM; uname; echo FOUND; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.10'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.9'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.8'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.7'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.6'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.5'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/bin/python3'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/libexec/platform-python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python2.7'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python2.6'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/bin/python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; echo ENDFOUND && sleep 0'"'"''
<XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX> (0, b'\r\n\r\nInvalid input detected.\r\n\r\nInvalid input detected.\r\n\r\nInvalid input detected.\r\n\r\nInvalid input detected.\r\n\r\nInvalid input detected.\r\n\r\nInvalid input detected.\r\n\r\nInvalid input detected.\r\n\r\nInvalid input detected.\r\n\r\nInvalid input detected.\r\n\r\nInvalid input detected.\r\n\r\nInvalid input detected.\r\n\r\nInvalid input detected.\r\n\r\nInvalid input detected.\r\n\r\nInvalid input detected.\r\n\r\nInvalid input detected.\r\n\r\nInvalid input detected.\r\n', b'')
[WARNING]: Unhandled error in Python interpreter discovery for host switch1: unexpected output from
Python interpreter discovery
Using module file /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/modules/setup.py
<XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX> PUT /home/ezeqielle/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-81594na5coq2q/tmpqpqwkpau TO Invalid input detected./AnsiballZ_setup.py
<XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d10 sftp -o BatchMode=no -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="test123"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/ezeqielle/.ansible/cp/bf6c4719ad '[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]'
[WARNING]: sftp transfer mechanism failed on [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed
information
<XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d10 scp -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="test123"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/ezeqielle/.ansible/cp/bf6c4719ad /home/ezeqielle/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-81594na5coq2q/tmpqpqwkpau '[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]:'"'"'Invalid input detected./AnsiballZ_setup.py'"'"''
[WARNING]: scp transfer mechanism failed on [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed
information
<XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: test123
<XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d10 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="test123"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/ezeqielle/.ansible/cp/bf6c4719ad XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 'dd of=Invalid input detected./AnsiballZ_setup.py bs=65536'
<XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX> (0, b'\r\n\r\nInvalid input detected.\r\n', b'')
<XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX> (0, b'\r\n\r\nInvalid input detected.\r\n', b'')
<XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: test123
<XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d10 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="test123"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/ezeqielle/.ansible/cp/bf6c4719ad XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chmod u+x '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'Invalid input detected./'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'Invalid input detected./AnsiballZ_setup.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
<XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX> (0, b'\r\n\r\nInvalid input detected.\r\n', b'')
<XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: test123
<XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d10 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="test123"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/ezeqielle/.ansible/cp/bf6c4719ad -tt XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'Invalid input detected./AnsiballZ_setup.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
<XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX> (0, b'\r\n\r\nInvalid input detected.\r\n', b'Shared connection to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX closed.\r\n')
fatal: [switch1]: FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {},
    "changed": false,
    "failed_modules": {
        "ansible.legacy.setup": {
            "ansible_facts": {
                "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
            },
            "failed": true,
            "module_stderr": "Shared connection to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX closed.\r\n",
            "module_stdout": "\r\n\r\nInvalid input detected.\r\n",
            "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
            "rc": 0,
            "warnings": [
                "Platform unknown on host switch1 is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python, but future installation of another Python interpreter could change the meaning of that path. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-core/2.12/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information."
            ]
        }
    },
    "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: ansible.legacy.setup\n"
}
```

I replaced the IP address with XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX. Thank you in advance for your help.

I attempted to:

- modify the path of Python for Ansible
- reinstall Python and Ansible to address any missing dependencies
- debug the issue using the logs and output obtained
- consulted the Ansible documentation.